# Covariance between residuals of different models in Bayesian linear regresion?

Tags: regression, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, inference, residuals

Suppose we have two features $x_1$ and $x_2$ and want to predict $y$ using a Bayesian framework (with isotropic gaussian noise). Assuming a gaussian prior and likelihood we have an analytical formulation for the parameter posterior distribution. Suppose I generate two predictive distributions, one using a model containing only x1. And another using a model containing x1 and x2. For a given test point, the predictive distribution and be converted to a non-central chi-squared distribution of residuals. Therefore we can get the variance of the mean sum of squared residuals (MSEs). If we do this for both models, is there an analytical way to relate the data and parameter posterior to the covariance between these two MSE distributions?

Comment: Could you please explain the setup in a bit more detail?

What is the relationship between $y$ and $x_1,x_2$? Is this a linear model?

Comment: Yes a linear model, i.e. $y=\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 + e, \quad e \sim N(0, 1)$